# MAMP page blank when login is included

Tags: php, authentication, mamp

MAMP newbie here. Just installed MAMP and placed a number of files in the directory. Access to the main page on the local host works fine when there's no authentication. However, when I add in the following to the top of the main file, and try to access it in browser, I get a blank page. pma-login.php is in the directory and it all works fine on the live server.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!session_is_registered(username)) {
    header("Location: pma-login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: This has been deopreciated and removed as of php 5.4: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php

Answer (score 1):

Changed it to the following and now is working:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: pma-login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Also, it would work to select PHP version 5.2 in MAMP in which the original code I used is not depreciated.